# Custom Field with Class component Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm using Formik as library to handle my form value. I'm trying to use a custom component as Field, my parent component looks like:

```
        <Formik
            onSubmit={(values) => {
                console.log(values);
            }}
        >{({values}) => (
            <div className="card-wrapper">
                <Form> 
                   <div className="row">
                       {group.elements.length ? (
                           group.elements.map((item,i) => {
                                  return (
                                    <div key={i} className="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                                           <Field type="range" component={LevelSelector} name={item.name.trim()} />
                                    </div>
                                  )
                           })
                        ): ""} 
                  <div className="btn-container">
                      <Input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Save"></Input>               
                  </div>
                </Form>
            </div>
        )}
        </Formik>
```

my custom component is a class component and not a function component. The documentation (https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field) shows me as could be implemented as function component but not as class component.

My render function looks like this:

```
render() {
    return(
    <>
        {
            ({
                field,
                form,
                ...props
            }) => {
                return(
                    <> 
                        <Label for="exampleSelect">{this.props.name}: </Label>
                        <p><i>{this.state.levelLabel}</i></p>
                        <Input {...field} {...props} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </>
                );
            }
        }
    </>
    );
```

I've tried to return function similar to the described in the documentation but not success.

Is there a way to implement custom field as class component?

Any helps will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Looking quickly at the docs you linked to, I don't see why you couldn't use a class component. Is the `render` function you've shared part of this (`LevelSelector` ?) component? What is not working about it currently?

Answer (score 2):

I make it work by using a class component (not a functional component).

On parent component use something like this:

```
import {Formik, Field} from 'formik';
import CustomComponent from '../path/to/CustomComponent/CustomComponent';
...
<Formik
someOtherProps
render=(() => (
  <Field name="customField" component={CustomComponent}
```

Then in your `CustomComponent` class you have two additional props to use formik methods

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class CustomComponent extends Component {
   /* you have these props, which access to
   this.props.field, // { name, value, onChange, onBlur }
   this.props.form   // { touched, errors, values, setXXXX, handleXXXX, dirty, isValid, status, ...etc }.
    */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Formik `Field` component will call your class component like you would do when using it normally in any other component. So the provided values are passed in as properties `field` and `form`. So you can access them normally like this `this.props.field.onChange` as single values or just pass all values directly to any child component.

```
render() {
 const {field} = this.props
 return (
   <input {...field}/>
 )
}
```